# Inheritance with Multiple Discriminators?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm still in the early stages of planning an application with a versatile Transactions system which will account for multiple transaction types and payment handlers.

Say I have the following base class:

```
public class Transaction {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TransactionTypes Type { get; set; }
    public PaymentHandlers PaymentHandler { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Where TransactionTypes is an enum which determines the type of the transaction. Below is an example when the transaction type is Product:

```
public class ProductTransaction : Transaction {
    public Address DeliveryAddress { get; set; }
}
```

And PaymentHandlers is an enum which determines the payment handler for the transaction. Below is an example when the payment handler is PayPal:

```
public class TransactionPayPal : Transaction {
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
}
```

However i'm not sure I've got this quite right as I have two different classes which inherit from Transaction with a different Discriminator. I assume there's some sort of rule against this as I can imagine this causing issues when inserting and getting the data later.

I'd appreciate advice on how this should be achieved. Thanks

Comment: You are building in logic within a given type (`Transaction`), to support different types? (`PaymentHandlers` enum) Smells like you should rethink your design and use proper polymorphism instead.

Comment: Did you check first that no open source project does this?

Comment: Thanks Steven. I have had a little re-think and have come up with something I think that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Steven's suggestion I have refactored my design. Now I have a TransactionHandler type which separates the handler information from the transaction. Finally I have added a join between these two classes (a foreign key in the database).